# XML drop shadow and different states

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to define a background for my ListView that has drop shadow and different colours for pressed state. Here's what I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding  android:bottom="1dp"  />
        <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp"  />
        <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/fublue" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_activated="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/fublue" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

However, that doesn't work. What do I need to change to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing for the drop-shadow, but for the press states, you must make your list view item layouts clickable. And then create a background selector drawable for your push states.

**Standard Style File**

*yourcolorstates.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:platformrq="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:background="#yourneutralcolor"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item
        android:background="#yourpressedcolor"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the `items` in a state `selector` and the states need to be be set.

example

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_focused="true">
         <shape>
            ...
         </shape>
      </item>
  </selector>
```